# Filter Items for Approval by Object Type

Tags: soql, approval-process

I'm trying to query for Approval Items which are outstanding for the running user to approve, filtering these approvals by the object type they are related to.

I've attempted to use the following SOQL, which works fine as an administrator:

```
     SELECT Id, ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId
       FROM ProcessInstanceWorkitem
USING SCOPE Mine_And_My_Groups
      WHERE ProcessInstance.Status = 'Pending'
             AND ProcessInstance.ProcessDefinition.TableEnumOrId IN ('Account', 'Contact')
```

Running as a "Standard User" profile I've encountered an error message:

```
System.UnexpectedException: Illegal filter on ProcessInstanceWorkitem
```

I've narrowed to down to the filter over `ProcessInstance.ProcessDefinition.TableEnumOrId` which is causing the issue. I can remove this filter, and subsequently filter by calling `getSObjectType()` against the `ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId` value, but would prefer to keep this efficient by filtering upfront.

Can anyone explain why my filter is illegal?

Test class which reproduces the issue:

```
@IsTest
static void testAsAdmin() {

    User u = getTestUser([SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'System Administrator'][0].Id);

    System.runAs(u) {
        //SUCCEEDS
        List<ProcessInstanceWorkitem> workitems = [
                SELECT Id, ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId
                FROM ProcessInstanceWorkitem
                USING SCOPE Mine_And_My_Groups
                WHERE ProcessInstance.Status = 'Pending'
                AND ProcessInstance.ProcessDefinition.TableEnumOrId IN ('Account', 'Contact')
        ];
    }
}

@IsTest
static void testAsStandardUser() {

    User u = getTestUser([SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'Standard User'][0].Id);

    System.runAs(u) {

        //FAILS
        List<ProcessInstanceWorkitem> workitems = [
                SELECT Id, ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId
                FROM ProcessInstanceWorkitem
                USING SCOPE Mine_And_My_Groups
                WHERE ProcessInstance.Status = 'Pending'
                AND ProcessInstance.ProcessDefinition.TableEnumOrId IN ('Account', 'Contact')
        ];
    }
}

static User getTestUser(Id profileId) {
    return new User(
            Alias = 'test',
            Email = 'exampletestuser@example.com',
            EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8',
            FirstName = 'Testing',
            LastName = 'Testing',
            LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US',
            TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles',
            LocaleSidKey = 'en_US',
            UserName = 'exampletestuser@example.com',
            ProfileId = profileId
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just hit this myself. The problem is documented here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000352954&type=1&mode=1

Where it says:

> For performance reasons, for users without the View All Data profile
> permission, Salesforce limits the entities that can be joined in a
> SOQL query on ProcessInstanceWorkItem.
>
> A SOQL query on ProcessInstanceWorkItem filtering on Actor.Name would
> require a join with User/Group which is not allowed by Salesforce for
> performance reasons for users without the View All Data profile
> permission. For these users, a SOQL query on this entity can only be
> joined with ProcessInstance.
>
> Additionally, if filtering on the ProcessInstanceWorkItem's actor is
> required, consider filtering on ActorId instead.

The last paragraph is the important one: If you know the ids, you can avoid having to joins. The end result is that you can achieve the result that you want, but you have to do it in multiple steps. Query `ProcessDefinition`, then `ProcessInstance`, then `ProcessInstanceWorkItem`.

In terms of your test, this becomes:

```
@IsTest
static void testAsStandardUser() {

    User u = getTestUser([SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'Standard User'][0].Id);

    System.runAs(u) {

        List<ProcessDefinition> processDefinitions = [
                SELECT Id
                FROM ProcessDefinition
                WHERE TableEnumOrId IN ('Account', 'Contact')
        ];

        List<ProcessInstance> processInstances = [
            SELECT Id
            FROM ProcessInstance
            WHERE ProcessDefinitionId IN :processDefinitions
        ];
        
        List<ProcessInstanceWorkitem> workitems = [
                SELECT Id, ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId
                FROM ProcessInstanceWorkitem
                USING SCOPE Mine_And_My_Groups
                WHERE ProcessInstance.Status = 'Pending'
                AND ProcessInstanceId IN :processInstances
        ];
    }
}
```

And, yes, you really do need three queries. You get a similar error if you try `FROM ProcessInstance WHERE ProcessDefinition.TableEnumOrId IN ('Account', 'Contact')`

Comment: Thanks Aidan - this input is helpful. I think you meant to link to this - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000352954&type=1&mode=1? 
I think I need to have a bit of a play with optimising this set of queries for LDV - a broad query over all ProcessInstances makes me nervous, whereas you'd have hoped the combination of SCOPE Mine_And_My_Groups and ProcessInstance.Status = 'Pending' would never result in a lot of rows :)

Comment: You're right, wrong link. I had too many tabs open with all my approval woes :( I've updated the link in the answer. The whole thing seems quite archaic, maybe the performance concerns that drove it are not so much of a concern any more and the SF should revisit the restriction

Comment: So I think you can compress this into 2 queries: one for the process definitions by object, and then a where clause on ProcessInstance.ProcessDefinitionId IN :processDefinitions. Saves a broad query over ProcessInstance at least.